# yocto - local build stuck on running do_compile tasks for two library

Tags: yocto, system-requirements, meta-raspberrypi

I am trying to build a core-image-minimal image raspberry pi 4 target machine.

For the setup project;

- I am using latest dunfell distribution version which is 3.1.12
- I added onl poky, meta-openembedded and meta-raspberrypi layers and also added those to the bblayer.conf
- I changed Machine field as raspberrypi4 in the local.conf file

So I do have basic setup for raspberrypi but while bitbake on my linux laptop, the progress is being stuck on these two do_compile task in below image.

[image]

I know it should suppose to take longer when you use local laptop. But I did run this job yesterday, and it was still stuck on this two tasks after running 14 hours, so I had cancelled. But now again it stuck on this two task, so I wonder if something is wrong, or I am missing something.

My linux laptop system information:

- Available storage space: 124 GB
- AMD Ryzen™ 5 PRO 3500U Processor (4 Cores / 8 Threads, 2.10 GHz, up to 3.70 GHz with Max Boost, 2 MB Cache L2 / 4 MB Cache L3)
- 8 GB of RAM
- Ubuntu 20.4

Do you have any suggestions, what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS onto my laptop, it has able to run this do_compile() tasks and build the entire image successfully.

I think Ubuntu 20.04 is not supported entirely, even thought the Yocto documentation says that is a supported Linux distribution. Furthermore, I think there is some not compitable packages somehow in my system which probably haven't tested with yocto community.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try clean it with `cleanall`?

```
$ bitbake -c cleanall openssl libtool
```

Also, you can look at build logs here:

```
build/tmp/work/<target-machine>/<program-name>/<version>/temp
```

Comment: I have run the 'bitbake -c cleanall openssl-native libtool-native', I saw that bitbake successfully has done. Then I run bitbake with verbose logs, and it didn't help. It still has stuck on those. Here is the verbose logs and also the logs from log folder: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uzyUP89uGxSpie9yhijyh05QJ5JiL2xd/view?usp=sharing